# kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin en MacOS

Tags: python, macos, video, kivy, gstreamer

Cuando hago clic en el botón que llama la función (v_player) para comenzar a reproducir un video corporativo obtengo este error:

```
File "kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx", line 233, in kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayer.load
 kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin
```

Estoy desarrollando  en un Mac (Mojave version: 10.14.5) usando PyCharm (2019.1.1).

```
Project Interpreter: (Python 3.7)
Cython           0.29.7 
Kivy             1.10.1 
Kivy-Garden  0.1.4  
Pygments     2.3.1  
certifi          2019.3.9   
chardet          3.0.4  
docopt           0.6.2  
docutils     0.14   
future           0.17.1 
gstreamer-player 1.1.2  
idna             2.8    
mutagen          1.42.0 
openstep-parser     
pbxproj          2.5.1  
pip          19.0.3
requests     2.21.0
setuptools   40.8.0 
urllib3          1.24.2 
wheel            0.33.1
```

He revisado la instalación, resinstalado o actualizado los siguientes paquetes:

```
gstreamer 
gst-plugins-base 
gst-plugins-good 
gst-plugins-bad 
gst-plugins-ugly
```

También hice esto pero sin ningún resultado positivo: 
(What did work was removing the 'gstplayer' in my kivy install. Where ever you kivy install is some where in 'site-packages/kivy/lib/gstplayer' Do rm -R site-packages/kivy/lib/gstplayer Again, this path should be replaced with your local installation path.

Based on the comments here in this issue on the kivy github site. There the directory is called 'gstreamer'. In my installation it was called 'gstplayer'.)

Y no me ha funcionado nada :(

Código en Ptyhon:

```
class Presentation(Screen):

    def v_player(self):
        if App.get_running_app().play == 0:
            App.get_running_app().play = 1
            App.get_running_app().video = Video(source='data/video/video.mp4')
            App.get_running_app().video.state = 'play'
            App.get_running_app().video.allow_stretch = True
            self.add_widget(App.get_running_app().video)
        else:
            App.get_running_app().play = 1
```

Código en el .kv:

```
        FloatLayout:
            ImageButton:
                source: 'data/icons/playback_play_icon48.png'
                size_hint: .5, .5
                pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.50, 'center_x': 0.50}
                on_press: root.v_player()
```

He buscado y leído mucho en Google, he reinstalado todo, he intentado diferentes soluciones como las descritas anteriormente pero sin ningún resultado positivo para solucionar el problema y al final sigo teniendo el mismo error.

¿Alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano

---

Intentado buscar el origen del problema he intentado reproducir un video que viene en los ejemplos de Kivy y el comando esta en la web de Kivy como ejemplo de prueba:

```
python3 -m kivy.uix.videoplayer Library/Python/3.7/share/kivy-examples/widgets/cityCC0.mpg
```

Y obtengo este error:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /Users/PC/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-07-05_6.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.1
[INFO   ] Python: v3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)]
[INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] VideoGstplayer: Using Gstreamer 1.10.4.0
[INFO   ] Video: Provider: gstplayer
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] GL: Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-12.9.22'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics 640'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] GL: Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[ERROR  ] Image: Error loading texture Library/Python/3.7/share/kivy-examples/widgets/cityCC0.mpg
[INFO   ] Base: Leaving application in progress...
[WARNING] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
[WARNING] stderr:     "__main__", mod_spec)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
[WARNING] stderr:     exec(code, run_globals)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/uix/videoplayer.py", line 677, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     runTouchApp(player)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
[WARNING] stderr:     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
[WARNING] stderr:     self._mainloop()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PCLibrary/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
[WARNING] stderr:     EventLoop.idle()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 346, in idle
[WARNING] stderr:     Clock.tick_draw()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 588, in tick_draw
[WARNING] stderr:     self._process_events_before_frame()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 427, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 467, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 465, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/uix/video.py", line 183, in _do_video_load
[WARNING] stderr:     self._video = CoreVideo(filename=filename, **self.options)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/core/video/video_gstplayer.py", line 56, in __init__
[WARNING] stderr:     super(VideoGstplayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 84, in __init__
[WARNING] stderr:     self.filename = kwargs.get('filename')
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 116, in <lambda>
[WARNING] stderr:     lambda self, x: self._set_filename(x),
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 113, in _set_filename
[WARNING] stderr:     self.load()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/PC/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/core/video/video_gstplayer.py", line 68, in load
[WARNING] stderr:     self.player.load()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx", line 233, in kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayer.load
[WARNING] stderr: kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin
```

¿Alguien que le pase lo mismo y sepa cómo resolverlo? Gracias...

---

He debugueado paso a paso y el único problema que he visto antes de que se cuelgue la app es:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_duration'

En el fichero: video_gsplayer.py 
In sefl properties:

```
duration: = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n File "/Aplications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 178, in _getPyDictionary\n'attr = getattr(var...
```

Alguna idea?